# confused about percentages in dimensions of web-app

Tags: css, html, margins

this is the first time, i'm building a totally scalable application with a css layout, when the user resizes the window the fields should shrink and grow accordingly. first i thought, easy, right? but now i'm really scratching my head over the dimensions, cause it seems like the margins are not quite right... i want to have a border-like separator thingy in between all the individual fields...

my code is this:

```
<div style='background-color:#000000;width:100%;height:100%;'>

    <div style='width:100%;height:66%;margin-bottom:1%;'>

        <div style='float:left; width:19%;height:100%;margin-right:1%;' class='app_14_concept_block'>keypartners</div>
        <div style='float:left; width:19%;height:100%;margin-right:1%;'>

            <div style='height:49%;margin-bottom:6%' class='app_14_concept_block'>key activities</div>

            <div style='height:49%;' class='app_14_concept_block'>key resources</div>

        </div>
        <div style='float:left; width:19%; height:100%;margin-right:1%;' class='app_14_concept_block'>value propositions</div>
        <div style='float:left; width:19%; height:100%;margin-right:1%;'>

            <div style='height:49%;margin-bottom:6%'  class='app_14_concept_block'>customer relationship</div>

            <div style='height:49%;' class='app_14_concept_block'>channels</div>

        </div>
        <div style='float:left; width:19%; height:100%;padding-right:1%' class='app_14_concept_block'>customer segments</div>
    </div>
    <div style='width:100%;height:33%;'>
        <div style='float:left; width:49%; height:100%;margin-right:1%;' class='app_14_concept_block'>cost</div>
        <div style='float:left; width:50%; height:100%;' class='app_14_concept_block'>revenue</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

the css is this:

```
.app_14_concept_block{
  background-color:#ffffff;
}
.app_14_concept_block:hover{
background-color:#eeeeee;
}
```

and this is what it looks like at the moment (the blue thingy there is part of my app viewer layout that would open comments) - my main concern is the added empty(black) space on the right, at the end of the rows:
[image: screenshot from my app inside my app viewer]

jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/gbMZy/51/

i also tried setting the "customer segments" width to 20% - sadly to no avail:

screenshot:[image]

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gbMZy/52/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this solution [Footer Items Expanding with Viewport Evenly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11244089/footer-items-expanding-with-viewport-evenly/11244216#11244216) could also work in your case.

Percentage width won't play well together with borders or margins.
A possible workaround is to have wrapper containers with full 20% / 50% width and then elements with border etc. **inside** them. This should help to avoid flickering and random spacings.

So, in your case this could look something like: http://jsfiddle.net/qC4JV/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="border right"></div>
        <div class="border bottom"></div>
        <p>value</p> 
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="border right"></div>
        <div class="border bottom"></div>
        <p>value</p>          
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="border right"></div>
        <div class="border bottom"></div>
        <p>value</p>           
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="border right"></div>
        <div class="border bottom"></div>
        <p>value</p>          
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="border bottom"></div>
        <p>value</p>           
    </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
    <div class="cell">
        <div class="border right"></div>
        <p>value</p>          
    </div>
    <div class="cell">
        <p>value</p>         
    </div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
body, html{
    height: 100%;
    background: #000;
}

.top{
    height: 60%;
}

.bottom{
    height: 40%;
}

.cell{
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
}

.cell .border.right{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

.cell .border.bottom{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #000;
}

.top .cell{
  width: 20%;
}

.bottom .cell{
  width: 50%;
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Set the font-size explicitly in the first div and then use 'em' to adjust the row margins.

But I'm unsure whether there will be scalability issues or not ..

Comment: When I use JSFiddle I see the extra black space isn't there anymore, did you make changes to the markup?

Comment: i noticed ^^ weird... well, just drag the result box and make it wider - the extra space will appear then

Comment: I dragged the box and it still didn't show. I didn't get why you added the padding-right: 1%; ..? instead, if you just make the fifth div to 20% it'll make the spacing go away .. Let me know if that works for you ..

Comment: maybe it's my browser, but in http://jsfiddle.net/gbMZy/50/ i still have the extra space - i'm gonna update my question with a screenshot

Comment: cool. thanks .. and do you need that 1% padding to the right in the original markup?

Comment: i don't, i'd just like to have all the columns in the first row to be about 20% width with some seperation in between, then for the columns that hold two subrows, i need the horizontal seperation there, same for the second row 50%/50% with a seperation.

Comment: I see - I'm gonna keep messing around with it cause it's starting to piss me off too! :) I'll let you know when I figure it out, cause I'm not stopping until I do hehe

Answer (score 0):

When using percentages in this manner, the way browsers round values to obtain discrete pixel values will often result in remainders. if 1% of the total width of the viewport is not an exact number of pixels, the browser will round up or down, resulting in a few pixels too many or too few, hence the jittery divs and unequal margins.

Even Twitter's Bootstrap framework, a very well developed system, suffers from the same issues when using its fluid grid system.

I hate to say it, but if you absolutely have to create a layout like this, and the unreliable element dimensions are not acceptable, using a table may be the way to go.

On the other hand, if you go with white 'borders' instead of black, the margin jitteriness will be less noticeable.

Comment: `using a table` > please try first with CSS2.1 `display: table(-cell|-row|-header-group|...)` before using HTML layout tables. If it doesn't work then yes maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is painful to read. You should really separate styles out into CSS instead of writing everything inline like that, it's harder to read/debug and makes it very easy to make a mistake.

Here is a little bit better of a solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gbMZy/51/

Answer (score 0):

Percentage always will be calculated in round values manner on browser and will be justified according to total width of body or parent element wrap area/width. These dimensions will be assign after calculating inner and outer pixels width given to sub elements or padding styles as well as border given on element with specified size of pixels too.

HTML:

```
<div class="top">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="border right">
    </div>
    <div class="border bottom">
    </div>
    <p>
      Top Block-1
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="border right">
    </div>
    <div class="border bottom">
    </div>
    <p>
      Top Block-2
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="border right">
    </div>
    <div class="border bottom">
    </div>
    <p>
      Top Block-1
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="border right">
    </div>
    <div class="border bottom">
    </div>
    <p>
      Top Block-3
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="border bottom">
    </div>
    <p>
      Top Block-4
    </p>

  </div>
</div>

<div class="bottom">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="border right">
    </div>
    <p>
      Bottom Block-1
    </p>

  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <p>
      Bottom Block-2
    </p>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Styles:

```
body, html{
  height: 100%;
  background: #3355A9;
}

.top{
  height: 60%;
}

.bottom{
  height: 40%;
}

.cell{
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  background: #ffca77;
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
  font-weight:bold;
}
.cell p{
  padding:10px;
}

.cell .border.right{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3355A9;
}

.cell .border.bottom{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background: #3355A9;
}

.top .cell{
  width: 20%;
}

.bottom .cell{
  width: 50%;
}
```

Try this solution on codebins: http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpbt

So, you might be found a better solution because it has better user interface and clear vision to display exact result as we want.